# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x40 in tid 13934

Tags: java, android, layout

I am trying to Extract songs thumbnails. But after extracting some of them 
Only 
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x40 in tid 13934  this error raise.Please help my or give me another solution to extract songs thumbnail.

```
   Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                    Log.i("Number",String.valueOf(i));
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    byte[] buffer;
                    try {
                        FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever fFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
                        fFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(arrayList.get(i));
                        buffer = fFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        buffer = null;
                    }

                    if (buffer != null) {
                        bitmap = resizeBitmap.resizeBitmap(buffer, 100, 100);
                    } else bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        File fos = new File(s + "/MyApp/data/thumbs", "image" + i + ".jpg");
                        if (!fos.exists()) {
                            fos.createNewFile();
                        }

                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fos);
                            if (!fos.exists()) fos.createNewFile();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
                            fileOutputStream.close();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you get this SIGNAL error because your image format does not match your decoder. Make sure you use the correct method to decode "/MyApp/data/thumbs/image". For example, get to know your image is either yuv or jpeg.